# Ignore initial data when parsing XML with Xerces

Tags: c++, c, xerces-c

I hope someone on here has some knowledge of using xerces-c. I have a string that contains a valid XML packet. It had however some leading data that has nothing to do with the XML. Is it possible to have the xerces-c SAXParser ignore any leading data and simply parse the first valid XML it finds? I am using an extremely simply setup without even the use of a DTD as below:

```
  SAXParser* lp_parser(0);

  MySaxHandler l_handler; 

  lp_parser->setDocumentHandler((DocumentHandler *)&l_handler);
  lp_parser->setDoNamespaces(false); 
  lp_parser->setDoNamespaces(false); 
  lp_parser->setDoSchema(false);
  lp_parser->setValidationSchemaFullChecking(false);

  MemBufInputSource lp_membuf((const XMLByte*)l_data.c_str(),
                              l_data.size(), 
                              "My XML request",
                              false);

  lp_parser->parse(lp_membuf);
```

The l_data is a `std::string` containing my XML packet including the initial data and `MySaxHandler` is where I save the few tags I am interested in. I can of course skip until I find the start of the XML myself but that is not the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: How much do you want to skip?

Comment: Everything up until the <xml .....  As I said - it isn't a problem doing this by hand .. I was just wondering if xerces had a way of just ignoring leading (& trailing) "rubbish"

Comment: What are you hoping for exactly? are these small requests? Could you use a DOM instead?

Comment: Well, you could try setExitOnFirstFatalError(const bool) as described here: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-sax-3.html But maybe it is really just better to look for the first occuring '<' and let the parser start there...